# CRM PFC frequency drop

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, control, power-factor-correction

When designing CRM PFC, I encountered an issue with the switching frequency. In theory, the frequency waveform appears as expected.

[image]

However, during simulation using a tool, I observed a drop in frequency. I suspect that the issue may be due to the small inductor current. Nevertheless, I am uncertain and would appreciate an explanation from someone knowledgeable in this area.

Any method that could solve this issue?

My simulation result:
[image]

Verbal Kint result:

[image]

Boost PFC circuit:

[image]

Comment: You say a small inductor size--but you don't specify what that size is. Show us a schematic, including a specific part number for the inductor.

Comment: @Hearth, 
Sorry, not the small size inductor, it is a small inductor current in the picture.
the schematic is a typical CrM boost PFC.

Comment: Did you try to zoom-in the inductor current and see what happens when frequency deviates significantly?

Comment: Maybe your design just stopped working in the low voltage parts of the rectified waveform?

Comment: @VerbalKint, 
Yes, I did. but I don't see any special after I zoom in on the waveform.
Could you let me know what should I know after I zoom in?

Comment: @Andyaka, 
Frequency drop is a normal situation?

Comment: @PowerJJ, did you try my [BCM template](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) and see if it behaves differently?

Comment: @VerbalKint Yes, I did. I use the file named "Boost CM PFC sine full version" The frequency always drops when the inductor is small.
I also post my simulation result there. 
both frequencies will drop when the inductor becomes 0.